# rails db:migrate fails on creating an index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm taking over maintenance of a Rails application that's several years old. Couldn't get the current version (https://github.com/rwestgeest/propile) working, and after talking to the current maintainer I set out on upgrading the ruby version from 2.3 to 2.5.5 and rails from 3.2.22 to 5.2.3.
Unfortunately that was a lot of work and I've had to change a huge amount of code.

I finally seem to have a working system, and I think I've got the unit tests in good shape too, but when I wanted to set up the test environment I got an error when running "rails db:migrate".
I've searched various places and found similar questions but they all seem to have a different cause. The only clue I currently have is that I'm developing on Windows and somewhere (lost the place unfortunately) it was suggested it could be a Windows-only issue?

I'm not a very experienced Ruby developer (I grew up programming Cobol and assembly, and have drifted into non-programming work; programming is one of my hobbies these days) and struggling to figure out why the migration doesn't work.

I have no clue what the minimal, reproducible example would look like. I guess it would involve all the (generated) migration scripts up to and including the one that fails. Here is the failing script:

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.integer :score
      t.references :session
      t.references :presenter

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :reviews, :session_id
    add_index :reviews, :presenter_id
  end
end
```

Note: I had to modify all migration scripts to add [5.2]

This is the output I get:

```
D:\dev\propile>rails db:migrate
== 20120520144512 CreateReviews: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:reviews)
   -> 0.0044s
-- add_index(:reviews, :session_id)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_reviews_on_session_id' on table 'reviews' already existsD:/dev/propile/db/migrate/20120520144512_create_reviews.rb:11:in `change'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: Index name 'index_reviews_on_session_id' on table 'reviews' already exists
D:/dev/propile/db/migrate/20120520144512_create_reviews.rb:11:in `change'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: You could try just commenting out the line which adds the index on session_id ... it's telling you the index already exists

Comment: My suspicion is that the older rails version did not automatically add an index when you add the foreign key using `t.references`, but the newer version does

Comment: I'd be curious if the issue still happens in `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: @maxpleaner That is indeed what has happened, starting with Rails 4 I think, but don't quote me on that

Comment: thanks @maxpleaner, if I comment out the line which adds the index it moves on. It then fails on the next index, but I can fix that :)

Comment: thanks @anothermh, but the db:drop fails for me. Perhaps that was the Windows specific issue I stumbled across